# Box Python SDK - Getting access_denied_insufficient_permissions while trying to create a webhook

Tags: python, webhooks, http-status-code-403, box-api

I'm trying to create a webhook for a folder on Box such that when the file is uploaded I get a notification.

```
from boxsdk import OAuth2, Client

auth = OAuth2(
    client_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxo',
    client_secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxh',
    access_token='xxxxxxxxxMj2',
)

client = Client(auth)


folder = client.folder(folder_id='1')

webhook = client.create_webhook(folder, ['FILE.UPLOADED'], <HTTPS_URL>)
print('Webhook ID is {0} and the address is {1}'.format(webhook.id, webhook.address))
```

The Error:

> Status: 403 Code: access_denied_insufficient_permissions

I also tried using the JWTAuth method and generated a Public/Private key pair

```
from boxsdk import JWTAuth, Client

config = JWTAuth.from_settings_file('./config_box_demo.json')


client = Client(config)

folder = client.folder(folder_id='1')


webhook = client.create_webhook(folder, ['FILE.UPLOADED'], <HTTPS_URL>)
print('Webhook ID is {0} and the address is {1}'.format(webhook.id, webhook.address))
```

But it displays the same error.

**Things I have already done:**

- Enabled all application scopes (include 'Manage Webhooks')
- Activated 'Perform Actions As Users' and 'Generate User Access Token'
- Authorised the App from Admin Console

Any help/tips would be appreciated.

Also, does it show the same error if theres an issue with the HTTPS URL?

Comment: Under Configuration > Authentication Method? OAuth 2.0 with JWT (Server Authentication)

Comment: use standard authorization, after creating a new app

Comment: and its access token expires after an hour

Comment: Nah, still doesn't work. I don't know, maybe some issue with the python SDK as I'm not getting any issues without using the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Two things might be causing an issue here. Firstly, make sure you application is configured to have the scope enabled to create webhooks.

[Webhook configuration screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zalx.png)

Secondly, it is important that the user who the access token belongs to actually has access to the folder you are trying to add a webhook to. In the case of a JWT authenticated app, the user is actually a service account that does not actually have access to your (a regular user) files and folders. You can read more on our user model here.

https://developer.box.com/en/guides/authentication/user-types/

Comment: Can you replace the second link with a functional URL?